# Куда задать вопрос про "посоветоваться"?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

У меня есть вопрос, по выбору библиотеки для JS, но на обычном [Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), его не задать, как минимум потому, что невозможно дать однозначно правильного ответа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда такие вопросы можно задавать? Или может на стеке нет такого места, куда можно с таким пойти?

Comment: Можно попробовать [здесь](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, все верно, советы - это не то зачем приходят на ruSO. Вопросы такого характера порождают вкусовщину и споры на ровном месте. Получается, что конкретный ответ, который был бы верным дать не возможно.

С другой стороны есть возможность задать вопрос с указанием метки [поиск-библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba) или [поиск-программ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc).

Если заглянуть в описание метки [поиск-программ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc), то можно увидеть следующее описание, которое вполне употребительно для вопросов такого характера

> Для выполнения какой-то конкретной задачи ищется программа. Чётко опишите задачу и требования к программе. Если известны программы, которые не подошли, перечислите их и поясните, почему именно они не подошли. Вопросы "какая программа лучше" являются оффтопиком в случае отсутствия чётких критериев сравнения.

такой подход можно применить и к поиску библиотек. Описать что вам надо, требования, что пробовали/использовали, что не подошло или почему вы пришли к выводу, что надо обратиться к поиску.

Comment: Очень доходчиво, спасибо! а на стеке нет подобного места где, можно пустится в полемику и споры? возможно в таких ситуациях когда уходит в спор намного легче выбрать то, что нужно

Comment: есть [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) в том числе и политикой (для особо дерзких), но как по мне очень там тихо